# How to build pyobjc from src

Tags: python, macos, pyobjc

I am trying to build pyobjc from src, so I checked out http://svn.red-bean.com/pyobjc/trunk

but I have no clue after that what I do to build it, I do not see any make or setup files?

**Edit 1:**
I tried setup.py in trunk/pyobjc/pyobjc folder but it tries to download all the required modules which seem to be already in trunk/pyobjc e.g. it says (if I switch off my internet)

> No local packages or download links
>   found for
>   pyobjc-framework-XgridFoundation==2.3b1

but trunk/pyobjc has pyobjc-framework-XgridFoundation

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. The documentation in the http://svn.red-bean.com/pyobjc/trunk/pyobjc/pyobjc-core/Install.txt explains the process

Comment: +1 for looking into this, but problem with that setup file is that it starts downloading all the stuff which is already in  /trunk/pyobjc/pyobjc